How to use both loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:) and loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:) in iOS?

My local html file contains remote resources with relative path.
And, I need to use local path resources.(specific local directory's contents)

To fulfill No.1 needs, I can use loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:).
To fulfill No.2 needs, I cna use loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:).

But, I need both of them. How can I solve this situation?

You can't have relative paths to a remote resource in a local file

@Paulw11 If I use loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:), it is working. Is it works but illegal?

Why would it be illegal?

The illegal mean that just no typical(or normal) way. Sorry, I'm not good at English. I used loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:) and I explicitly replaced the relative paths with the absolute paths. Then, almost success but, somtimes fail... :(

In iOS, WKWebView doesnt support loading a local HTML file with remote resources directly using both loadFileURL(:allowingReadAccessTo:) & loadHTMLString(:baseURL:) in the same request.
However, you can achieve your goal by reading the local HTML file as a string, then using loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:) with the appropriate base URL to access both local and remote resources.
Here’s how:

Load the HTML Content as a String: Read the local HTML file content
and load it as a string.
Set the baseURL: Use the directory URL containing your local
resources as the baseURL in loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:). This will
allow access to both local and remote resources referenced with
relative paths.



How does that work?  Either the base url is the local directory or it is the remote server.  It can't be both at the same time

In example, the remote base URL is https://www.google.com. The local path is a local directory path and images are in this directory. But, the local images are not a static. They will be saved dynamically. For example, will be saved image files extracted by PhotoKit in the iPhone.

I decided to use only loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:) and in case of local image, I put the Data URL type string by base64 encoded in img tag.
